# Offline sort of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm currently using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to retrieve data from a Firebase database, and I've pretty much worked out how to retrieve the data in the order I desire.

To avoid duplication and ease database maintenance, I'd like to add a key to a database entry that allows me to return queries based on that key.  I was originally storing data twice.  Once for all to see, and once if a user had joined a certain group (under groupName).

To return a query based on group, my original search was as follows:

```
databaseReference.child(groupName).child("exerciseId"+mExerciseId).orderByChild(sortOrder).limitToFirst(100);
```

but I believe duplication can be avoided by adding the key "group" to my post. (it also make maintenance much easier as users switch groups).

The "group" database query has now become:

```
databaseReference.child("exerciseId"+mExerciseId).orderByChild("group").equalTo(groupName);
```

All is good, except that the data is no longer sorted as per "sortOrder".  As firebase does not allow multiple sort criteria, I believe my solution lies in offline sorting.

So, how does one sort the adapter offline?

My adapter is pretty standard:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(Post.class, R.layout.item_post, PostViewHolder.class, dataQuery)

{

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(final PostViewHolder viewHolder, final Post model, final int position)
    {

        final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

        // Bind Post to ViewHolder, setting OnClickListener for the star button
        viewHolder.bindToPost(model, position, postRef.getKey(), null);

    }

    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

I've implemented Comparable in Post, the problem is where is the data stored so that I can pass it to Collections.sort() in this sort of way:

```
private List<Post> mPosts = new ArrayList<>();
mPosts.add(model);

Collections.sort(mPosts, Post.Comparators.ALLTIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

The adapters in the FirebaseUI library currently always display data in the order that it is returned by the underlying `FirebaseDatabase` reference or `Query`.

You could file a [feature request on the Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues) for it (since I'm not sure it is covered in [this one](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/15) yet). Alternatively you could fork the library and roll your own implementation of this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.  It's working without the simplification, so I'll come back to it when my 20 other items are done ;-)   Are chained queries, or chained sort criteria something on the upcoming feature list for Firebase?  It'd be great to show the top 100 leaderboard results and then add in the user to the list if they are not already shown, or show 50 either side of the current user.  All nice enhancements, but not essential.  Thanks again.

Comment: I guess thinking about this some more, I could populate my own List based on a single query, and then sort it / add to it, and then show all the results in a recyclerview.  Not sure how I would populate a list based on a Firebase query - I'll have to search, unless you have a link to a good example?

Answer (score 0):

To feedback on the solution I came up with.  I ended up populating my own List, which I can then sort or add to (if using multiple queries) depending on what I'm trying to achieve.  This is then displayed using a standard RecyclerView adapter.  It works great.

```
private final List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>();

dataQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        postList.clear();   // in this example it's a newQuery, so clear postList
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Post post = child.getValue(Post.class);
            postList.add(post);

            int myPosition = sortData();    // uses Collections.sort() to sort data

            mAdapter.addPosts(postList);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mRecycler.scrollToPosition(myPosition);
        }
    }
});
```